# restart gnome shell command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome

Say that after modifying some stuff in the gnome shell i want to restart the gnome desktop. What I'd do normally is press Alt+F2 to restart it, but i want to automate it in a script that installs stuff and then  reloads the desktop. I've found that the equivalent is `gnome-shell -r` but whenever I run it my desktop crashes and I'm forced to log out. Alt+F2 runs with no problems. What's going on and is it correct that the command stated above is the equivalent to Alt+F2? If so why is it not working propery, when alt+f2 does never cause a crash?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo killall -HUP gnome-shell
```

Comment: The answers on the duplicate target nowhere mentioned Signal Hang UP and IMO this is a good answer. Would you like to post there?